# Magento Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Order_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I must be over-thinking this issue, but I can't seem to resolve it.  I need to overwrite the **sendNewOrderEmail** function of **Mage_Sales_Model_Order**.  When I do this I lose my transactional email templates in the drop-down in the admin interface.

Error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Order_Helper_Data' not found
```

/app/code/local/Mine/Sales/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order>Mine_Sales_Model_Order</order>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <sales>
                <class>Mine_Sales_Helper</class>
            </sales>
        </helpers>
        <template>
            <email>
                <umicrosite_order_alert module="order">
                    <label>Vendor Order Alert</label>
                    <file>umicrosite_order_alert.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </umicrosite_order_alert>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Mine/Model/Sales/Order.php

```
<?php
class Mine_Sales_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order
{
    /**
     * Send email with order data
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
     */
    public function sendNewOrderEmail()
    {
        $storeId = $this->getStore()->getId();

        $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('umicrosite_order_alert');
        $emailTemplate->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/email'));
        $emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/name'));
        $emailTemplate->setType('html');
        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('New Order from my store');
        $emails = array();
        foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
            $vendor = Mage::helper('udropship')->getVendor($item->getProduct());
            $email = $vendor->getEmail();
            if (!in_array($email,$emails)) {
                $emails[] = $email;
                $emailTemplateVariables = array();
                $emailTemplateVariables = array('vendor_name'=>$vendor->getVendorName());
                $emailTemplate->send($email, $vendor->getVendorName(), $emailTemplateVariables);
            }
        }
        parent::sendNewOrderEmail();
    }
}
```

/app/code/local/Mine/Sales/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Mine_Sales_Helper_Data extends Mage_Sales_Helper_Data
{

}
```

If I change my Data.php to:

```
class Mage_Order_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
```

It causes Class 'Mine_Sales_Helper_Data' not found.

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: did you use `Mage::Helper('something')` anywhere in your module ?

Comment: I added my module to the question details

Comment: so in your model, you have this code `Mage::helper('udropship')`. Where is this helper defined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to extend your helper from  `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`.

```
<?php
class Mine_Sales_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Actually you don't want to define helper for your extension, if it just rewrite a model class. So if you remove the helper definition from `config.xml` file, it should work. Try it

### EDIT

Ah.. Why didn't I notice it before. you put this code in your config file

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order>Mine_Sales_Model_Order</order>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <mine_sales> <!-- helper alias; IT SHOULD BE UNIQUE; so avoid 'sales' -->
                <class>Mine_Sales_Helper</class>
            </mine_sales>
        </helpers>
        <template>
            <email>
                <umicrosite_order_alert module="mine_sales">
                    <label>Vendor Order Alert</label>
                    <file>umicrosite_order_alert.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </umicrosite_order_alert>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
</config>
```

The problem was here. `<umicrosite_order_alert module="order">`. Here you have specified module as `order`. This in fact look for a helper with alias `order`. Magento trying to find it. But it is not defined. Hence show this error.

Here you are set helper alias to `mine_sales`. So you have to specify it there inside `module` attribute. Now try it. It will definitely work

Note: you need to use my helper defintion  here. If you use your own helper defintion, there is no problem with that. Since the class that extend your helper class is `Mage_Sales_Helper_Data` which is infact a child of `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`. But you don't need to do that. You can directly extend `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract` in this case.

Comment: Without the helper definition I get Class 'Mine_Sales_Helper_Data' not found and I have not templates under Transactional Emails.

Comment: so in your model, you have this code `Mage::helper('udropship')`. Where is this helper defined ?

Comment: @programmer_rkt With your code I get this error again: Class 'Mage_Order_Helper_Data' not found
I found in a community extension this defined
        <helpers>
            <udropship>
                <class>Unirgy_Dropship_Helper</class>
            </udropship>
        </helpers>

Comment: @input  : Friend, I really wanna know where helper `sales` defined ? Can you find it for me ?

Comment: Is that extension already installed in your system ? Then most probably it makes problem

Comment: @programmer_rkt there is a helper defined at /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper.  Are you looking for a different one?

Comment: @HarmonicApps : Yes you are right. But I am talking about helper definition config file. That means that helper should defined in any one of the config.xml file. Most probably it should be in `Mage_Sales`. But unfortunately, I couldn't find that definition

Comment: @HarmonicApps : try this. comment all codes inside in your model file. Leave model definition uncommented of course(means it should persist in your code). Make sure my code in your helper class.clear cache and refresh the page again. And tell me the resutl

Comment: @programmer_rkt I was so hoping this would work, but it didn't.
PHP Fatal error: Class 'Mine_Sales_Helper_Data' not found
And I removed the helpers definition from the config.xml

Comment: no you have to keep helper definition in config file. Also your order.php lies in wrong place. It should be in `Mine/Sales/Model/Order.php`

Comment: I have edited my answer. Now try again with that update. It may solve the issue

Comment: There were 2 issues in my config.xml: 1 - needed to alias the helper like <mine_sales>, 2 - needed to reference the module like module="mine_sales" in my template email section.  Thank you so much for not giving up on me! :)

Comment: ya you can use anything for alias your helper. You can use `my_helper` or `my_baby`. Then you need to use that alias then. Only rule for that alias is, it should be unique :) Happy to help you